# How do I print or export an HTML table as PDF with CSS styling, while keeping the page size (device independent)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print an HTML and CSS styled Table (or export it as PDF).

After doing some research and programming on my own and using some popular libraries, I have had some issues.

When trying to print (export as PDF), I want the Table to always look the same (A4 sheet) independent of the device that the print function is being used on.

The problem is that it prints the Table exactly as it looks like on the current screen. For example, on small screens the Table does not even fit on the screen and is cut off at some point (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAo9X.png) which shows this effect).

Another problem is that even if the Table fits on the screen (for example, on laptops), it still looks different to the one on bigger screens, because they are stretched in a different way to fit on A4.

How can I either print or export it as PDF (I would prefer to export it as PDF) so that it looks the same on every device, no matter how big or how small the screen is?

By the way, the Table is generated dynamically with PHP with Data from a MySQL Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that you need to have a look on the following plugin.
Sure many others exist.

You will need to render the pdf on the backend with a library or something.
I have used pd4ml and it was good. You can create separate styles/css/html and export them with data that you pass in.

Have a look on this,
https://pd4ml.com/php.htm

Also you should have a look on PhantomJS but this requires extra software to be installed.

PD4ML is just a small library that can be used.

Comment: It is just a small server though with a maximum of 100 current users. Isn't this very resource heavy and might crash the server?

Comment: I have used it on my local machine and that's a small machine! We didn't have any issues on our production machine, and we did some heavy processing for the rendering. Guess you will need to have a look if it does your job! ps we used java on it however.

Comment: Just saw that this only supports a php wrapper and that the machine needs to have java installed... Sorry:)

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 <input type = "button" value = "Print" onclick = "window.print()" />
```

```html
<h1> THIS IS PRINT EXAMPLE: </h1>
<h3> ALL SNIPPET WILL BE PRINTED </h3>

             <input type = "button" value = "Print" onclick = "window.print()" />
```

This might help you